# Building TFLite 2.14.0 static library using cmake and NDK 26b for native Android projects

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, android-ndk, c++17, tensorflow-lite

Has anyone been able to build TFLite 2.14.0 static library using cmake and NDK 26b for native Android projects? I am able to build Tensorflow 2.14.0 lite with NDK 26b but with some issues that linker walks away with undefined symbols later on. I am aware that the recommended NDK for reliably building tensorflow is 21e as of writing date of my post, I have read the tensorflow git issues pages and could find a satisfactory answer there. Some of the posts suggested that tensorflow might have started supporting NDK 25c builds but even that fails when used to build the project. I am able to create the static library but using it my project throws it off with undefined symbols.

Here's the build command using cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK_ROOT/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=28 \
-DTFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_NNAPI=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_GPU=OFF \
-DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF -DTFLITE_ENABLE_MMAP=OFF \
-DTENSORFLOW_LITE_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON ../tensorflow/lite

cmake --build . -j 8
```

Here NDK_ROOT is set to NDK 26b (and alternatively 25c) home directory.

Weid things happen after the configuration step that even after disabling RUY with -DTFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=OFF, it keeps showing RUY is turned on and produces the libtensorflow-lite.a static fine but when using this static library in my project build stops with linker errors on a bunch of undefined RUY and other rfft2d symbols (deeper symbol references have been removed here for clarity):

```
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::get_ctx(ruy::Context*)
  >>> referenced by ruy.h:47 (ruy/ruy/ruy.h:47)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Ctx::clear_performance_advisories()
  >>> referenced by frontend.h:90 (ruy/ruy/frontend.h:90)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::MulFrontEndFromTrMulParams(ruy::Ctx*, ruy::TrMulParams*)
  >>> referenced by frontend.h:94 (ruy/ruy/frontend.h:94)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Ctx::SelectPath(ruy::Path)
  >>> referenced by create_trmul_params.h:423 (ruy/ruy/create_trmul_params.h:423)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: rdft2d
  >>> referenced by rfft2d.cc:308 (/Developer/ThirdParty/TensorFlow/tensorflow-2.14.0/tensorflow/lite/kernels/rfft2d.cc:308)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::ThreadPool::ExecuteImpl(int, int, ruy::Task*)
  >>> referenced by thread_pool.h:77 (ruy/ruy/thread_pool.h:77)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: util::Fingerprint64(char const*, unsigned long)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Context::set_max_num_threads(int)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Context::Context()
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: pthreadpool_destroy
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Ctx::set_performance_advisory(ruy::PerformanceAdvisory)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Ctx::GetMainAllocator()
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Kernel8bitNeonDotprod1Col(ruy::KernelParams8bit<8, 8> const&)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Kernel8bitNeonDotprodA55ish(ruy::KernelParams8bit<8, 8> const&)
  >>> referenced by kernel_arm.h:125 (ruy/ruy/kernel_arm.h:125)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Kernel8bitNeonDotprodX1(ruy::KernelParams8bit<8, 8> const&)
  >>> referenced by kernel_arm.h:127 (ruy/ruy/kernel_arm.h:127)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Kernel8bitNeonDotprod(ruy::KernelParams8bit<8, 8> const&)
  >>> referenced by kernel_arm.h:129 (ruy/ruy/kernel_arm.h:129)
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Context::~Context()
  
  ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: ruy::Kernel8bitNeon1Col(ruy::KernelParams8bit<4, 4> const&)
  >>> referenced by kernel_arm.h:70 (ruy/ruy/kernel_arm.h:70)
  
  ld.lld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use --error-limit=0 to see all errors)
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried NDK 25c as well but that also runs into exactly the same problem, just that with the different set of undefined symbols. objdump/nm show these symbols are undefined.

Project builds and runs fine when tensorflow 2.0.0 is built with NDK 21e and used in the project.

Comment: It is possible that I am missing external libraries that need to be included with the libtensorflow-lite.a, but I thought the point of having lite was to have just one single all encompassing static library. At least with tf-lite 2.0.0 and NDK 21e that's how it worked.

Comment: I tried linking to all the other RUY libraries but I still get linking errors, albeit different ones now.