# Latest NDK version that builds tensorflow lite 2.14.0 static libs

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

This is with respect to my other question on SO, I am not too sure if it demanded a separate question since this one is always going to be time bound.

[Building TFLite 2.14.0 static library using cmake and NDK 26b for native Android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77618966/building-tflite-2-14-0-static-library-using-cmake-and-ndk-26b-for-native-android)

As per tensorflow developer group, latest NDK that's recommended is 21e. What I am wondering is if anyone has tried later versions of NDK to build tensorflow lite and has been successful in running it with their native Android projects? 21e seems to be working for me as well but my attempts with 25c and 26b have failed.